# What is the meaning of Altitude in EXIF of an image?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, accuracy, exif

Currently I have some photographs​ captured by DJI, and in their EXIF I saw that it contains: GPS Altitude, Absolute Altitude, Relative Altitude, GPS Latitude, GPS Longitude.

These images will be used for creating TIFF file by Pix4D. After creating TIFF file from those images, I use the GPS Lat/Long of one of those images and then extract the elevation from TIFF file and that elevation is different with the altitude from the image.  I also use Google Elevation API and it also different from the altitude of the image (and the elevation from my raster, too).

For example, with this lat/lon (GPS value from EXIF) 15.99849675/108.246482777778 I get those 3 values​:

- Altitude (GPS and Absolute) in the EXIF: 62.9m Above Sea Level
- Relative Altitude: 49.80
- Elevation I get from TIFF: 21.9400272369
- Elevation I get from Google API: 4.45

So my questions are:

- What is the meaning of the altitude in EXIF of an image?
- The accuracy between the elevation extract from TIFF and the Google elevation API

Comment: Have you checked what the EXIF specification says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest EXIF specification http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2016-E.pdf knows only GPSAltitudeRe and GPSAltitude. They are defined as

> GPSAltitudeRef  Indicates  the  altitude  used  as  the  reference 
>   altitude.  If  the  reference  is  sea  level  and  the  altitude  is 
>   above sea level, 0 is given. If the altitude is below sea level, a
>   value of 1 is given and the altitude is  indicated as an absolute
>   value in the GPSAltitude tag. The reference unit is meters. Note that
>   this tag is BYTE type, unlike other reference tags.
>
> GPSAltitude  Indicates  the  altitude  based  on  the  reference  in 
>   GPSAltitudeRef.  Altitude  is  expressed  as  one   RATIONAL value.
>   The reference unit is meters.

Absolute and Relative altitudes seem to be some non-standard tags and you should ask DJI what they mean.

Comment: Thanh you very much