# What is the easiest way to find the ground altitude of an image taken by a drone

Tags: exif

I understand that the Exif Altitude metadata that is included in images taken by DJI Drones is based on sea level. It is not the Drone altitude from the actual ground.

What is the easiest way to find the ground altitude of the drone? (means the vertical distance between drone and ground)

Comment: There should Altitudes (in the Exif) be two GPSAltitude and GPSAltitudeREF > https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/242830/276

Comment: @Mapperz, all DJI camera provide is "GPS Altitude". I used Phil Harvey's exiftool(-k).exe and still can't find GPSAltitudeREF.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The GPS does't know the position of the ground once your drone is in the air. If your drone has some kind of range finder or memory of where it took off from or database of altitudes, then it could include it. There used to be a Google web service you could call with a lat/lng and it'd give you ground elevation, but I believe that's been discontinued.